# Azure - Leave Azure Subscriptions

Tags: azure

I have left a job which was using Azure around 5 years ago, however I can still see the subscriptions active in the Azure portal site (https://portal.azure.com). I would like to leave both subscriptions so my account is completely independent from that company. My account used is an @outlook account which was linked to Azure Portal back then. From my unerstanding, there are 2 subscriptions, in which I am Owner in both.

How can I achieve that?

I have tried leaving the organisation from https://myapps.microsoft.com as many sources suggested but nothing changed. When I try to use that page now, I get the following screen:

[image]

Happy to provide any info needed.